# Using GRASS algorithms in Sextante under ArcGIS Desktop?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, grass-gis, sextante

Sextante for ArcGIS comes with SAGA modules.

I know that I can use GRASS algorithms in Sextante under gvSIG.

But how can I use GRASS algorithms in Sextante under ArcGIS Desktop?

I tried to look for any instructions, but could not find any. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I found a blog entitled [SAGA and GRASS running in ArcGIS through SEXTANTE](http://sextantegis.blogspot.com.au/2011/08/here-is-another-video-of-sextante-on.html) which says:

> This time, I am showing how SAGA and SEXTANTE algorithms can be
>   executed just like native SEXTANTE algorithms. This is completely true
>   for SAGA ones, but I'm having a bit of trouble with GRASS ones,
>   specially vector ones. This is not a GRASS or SEXTANTE problem, but
>   just a problem caused by the strange behaviour of Java when I call the
>   application (SAGA or GRASS) from ArcGIS, since it freezes and I
>   haven't been able to solve it.

I have not been able to uncover any other reports of anyone succeeding at doing what you hope to.